# How to pass a list of objects from a JSP page to action class using url in struts 2?

Tags: java, struts2

I am getting a list of objects from one action class to a jsp page . Now I want to pass that list of objects to  another action class .Other action class will be  called using a URL. 
How do I acheive that ?

Comment: Pass the objects to the request (url or post parameters) or store them somewhere in the user's session (or a conversation if you're using the conversation plugin).

Comment: I used url to pass the object . It was not showing in the action class before . I solved it later by setting escape amp property in url to false . By default it was set to true due to which the whole object was not passed.